# Segmentation Fault: 11 when trying to run a C file that calculates and stores all combinations of a binary string in an array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, combinations

I have created a simple program to generate and store all combinations of numbers (up to 8 i this example) in binary in an array. However when i try and run the script the error message Segmentation Fault:11 appears. I can't figure out what is wrong..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
      int no,i=0,j;
      int *d;
      d = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);
      for(no=0;no<8;no+=1)
      {
      do
      {
           d[i]=no%2;
           i++;
           no=no/2;
      }while(no>0);
      }
      for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
      {
            printf("%d",d[j]);
      }

 }
```

Comment: what do you think the `do..while` loop is doing inside `for` loop with `no`?

Comment: also, please do not cast return value of `malloc()` and always check for the success of `malloc()`.

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger? Please read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/\

Comment: @EricLippert - I doubt it, since the problem would have been obvious.

Comment: @MartinJames: Indeed it would. Many novice developers seem to have this idea that you find bugs by thinking about it really hard. I say: you caused the problem with a computer, so solve the problem with a computer. Use a debugger. Write assertions. Use compiler warnings.

Comment: @james: Now that you know where the bug is, don't just fix it. Ask yourself "how could I have avoided this bug by better program design?" and "how could I have found this bug automatically?"  Learn from the mistake. For instance, had you made the inner loop a method of its own, you would not have written the bug in the first place. I internalized this rule the first time I made your mistake, and now I almost never write error-prone nested loops. A loop is non-trivial work, and non-trivial work goes into a method that does precisely one thing well.

Comment: ^^ what @EricLippert says.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, with the `do..while` loop inside `for` loop

```
do
      {
           d[i]=no%2;
           i++;
           no=no/2;
      }while(no>0);
```

in place is ending up changing the value of `no`, thus making the `for` loop run *apparently* forever, thus writing past the allocated memory for `d`.

Solution: use a new variable, say `int val` to use with `do..while` loop, and set its value equal to `no` in the first statement in `for` loop.

Side note:

1. Please  [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.
2. Always check for the success of `malloc()` [or, for that matter, any library function]

Comment: Though you're on the right track here, the real bug in my opinion is that badly-named-variable `I` is never reset to zero. It just gets bigger and bigger. That the program also has an infinite loop is not the problem that is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: @EricLippert Sir, I did not get the _reset to zero_ part. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Ah, I think this might have been my misunderstanding. I thought the intention of the program was to produce the array {0}, then the array {1}, then {1, 0}, then the array {1, 1}, and so on. But the program really is intended for some bizarre reason to produce {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, ... }. So `i` is intended to increase every time through the inner loop, not to be reset to the beginning of the array on each number. This is a very strange little program.  So: ultimately it is the fact that `i` gets too big that causes the fault, but it gets too big because of the infinite loop you identified.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes sir, once we get rid of the infinite loop, related problem should be solved. Nevertheless, thanks for making the point. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help Sourav and Eric. The reason I want to store a string of binary combinations is because I later want to extract them from the array and assign blocks of text to the values of 1 and 0 in correspondence with their position. This is because I am writing a large program that involves combinations of text and therefore I am searching for a way to automatically print out all the combinations. I have removed the infinite loop but the program still shows the Segmentation Fault: 11 error :(